# Off-canvas Sidebar - unable to set background color Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

After following [this url](http://www.bootply.com/92159) I am able to add the off-canvas sidebar menu to bootstrap. But I can't change the background color of the off-canvas sidebar. If I inspect element it grabs the background from the body tag. How can I change the background color to black for example?

Comment: Inspect the element using *browser's developer tool* will surely solve your problem. Visit this [**Link**](http://devtoolsecrets.com) .

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Already trying from past half an hour. But I am unable to change the background color of off-canvas sidebar menu

Comment: try using this `.sidebar-offcanvas { background: #f9a933;}` but also remove `background-color` from `.row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {`  in `@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {`.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Tried, its not working.

Comment: then its better to create a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas` to change the background of the sidebar. See working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle=offcanvas]').click(function() {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active');
    $('.showhide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/*
 * Off Canvas
 * --------------------------------------------------
 */
 .navbar.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .row.row-offcanvas {
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
        transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    }
    .row.row-offcanvas.row-offcanvas-right .sidebar-offcanvas {
        right: -60%;
        margin-right: 0px;
        background-color: #ccc; /**Change this**/
    }
    .row.row-offcanvas.row-offcanvas-left .sidebar-offcanvas {
        left: -50%;
    }
    .row.row-offcanvas.row-offcanvas-right.active {
        right: 60%;
    }
    .row.row-offcanvas.row-offcanvas-left.active {
        left: 50%;
    }
    .row.row-offcanvas .sidebar-offcanvas {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
    <div class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>

          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a>

          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class=" visible-xs">
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
            </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php" title="Menu 2">Menu 2</a> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas showhide navbar-collapse" id="sidebar" role="navigation" style="">
        <div class="sidebar-nav">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>

            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

                </li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="jumbotron">
            <h2>Off-canvas Sidebar Example</h2>

            <p>This is an example to show the potential of an offcanvas layout pattern in Bootstrap. Try some responsive-range viewport sizes to see it in action.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
            <div class="col-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>

              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#">View details »</a>

              </p>
            </div>
            <!--/span-->
          </div>
          <!--/row-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```